# Why do we do toString('hex') after crypto?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash, cryptojs, sha512

Why do we convert to string after hashing the password?

`u.password = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, iteration, keylen, digest).toString('hex');`

Comment: Because the result is a binary goo?

Comment: so it's in binary state after hashing

Comment: That depends on what you want to do with it next. a priori there is no reason at all to convert to hex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `crypto.pbkdf2Sync` is a binary value: harder to store, represent, pass over. Thus you can safely turn it to a hex representation, which is much more user friendly.

Comment: Tnx for that, all I needed to know!